# How to guarantee that class specializations are consistent

Tags: inheritance, uml, aggregation, composition

I have two Abstract Classes, representing an composition:

- *Country* (made of *People*)
- *People*

I have a concretization of these two classes in e.g.:

- *Country*: *France* and *Italy*
- *People*: *FrenchGuy* and *ItalianGuy*

The *Country* abstract class as a list of people as an attribute: **peopleList:People**

How can I **guarantee** that the *France* class peopleList attribute will be filled only with *FrenchGuy*, and *Italy* with *ItalianGuy*, and make it consistent ?

Does the way how I designed it is an **anti-pattern** ?

[image]

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: You have mixed up "is a kind of" with "is an instance of" in your example. That's a huge antipattern right there!

Comment: I might have time to explain how to do this right later today. Using a generalization set is a red herring.

Comment: @JimL.:  _You have mixed up "is a kind of" with "is an instance of" in your example._: Indeed it's my example which is not very well chosen. France and Italy in my case need to be _specialization_ and not _instances_. For example, _France_ would have a _getCheese()_ method, and _Italy_ a _getPizza()_

Comment: A class roughly corresponds to a _set of instances_. What instances are in the set called "France"? If you update the question with a viable diagram, I can tell you how to say that a thing on the left has only a more specific kind of thing on the right. I can't do that with an invalid example.

Comment: Ok, so let's use a classic Insurance example. Let's say that what I call 'Country' in the example above, is **Insurance**. 'France' and 'Italy' is **InsuranceType1** and **InsuranceType2**
Imagine that 'People' is **Position**. 'FrenchGuy' and 'ItalianGuy' is **CivilServant** and **CompanyEmployee**.
The thing is, how to connect **InsuranceType1** to **CivilServant**, and **InsuranceType2** to **CompanyEmployee** ?

Comment: I finally had time to write up something. Please see my answer, below, and let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this question with an example that does not confuse "is a kind of" with "is an instance of". (Please see my comments on the original question for more detail.)

You can, indeed, guarantee that specific specializations are only associated with certain other specializations. You can do this using UML association specialization and property redefinition.

[image: redefinition example diagram]

I'll give you a tour of what this UML diagram tells us:

- There is an unnamed association between `Insurance Policy` and `Insurable Thing` that has two properties: *insures* and *insured by*. It tells us that, in general, each `Insurance Policy` *insures* one or more `Insurable Things`, and each `Insurable Thing` may be *insured by* any number of `Insurance Policies`.¹
- An `Insurance Policy` has two disjoint² specializations: `Health Insurance Policy` and `Car Insurance Policy`.
- An `Insurable Thing` has two disjoint specializations: `Car` and `Person`.
- The unnamed association at the top has two specialized associations with more specific property constraints:

  - The association between `Car Insurance Policy` and `Car` has properties that **redefine** (i.e., tighten) their allowed types.
  - The association between `Health Insurance Policy` and `Person` has properties that **redefine** (i.e., tighten) their allowed types.

The specialized associations and the redefinitions are doing all the work here. If you like, you could further tighten the multiplicities or even change the property names³.

---

<sup>¹ Note that UML recently adopted a "dot notation" that makes the absence of dots on the ends of an association ambiguous. Pre dot notation, a navigable property was owned by the class on the other end of the association. Post dot notation, a navigable property is owned by the association--except for the fact that few tools support it, and those that do, such as MagicDraw, turn the dots *off* by default in the project options! I personally find the dot notation horrid, so this example does not use it, which means the properties are owned by the class on the opposite end of its association.</sup>

<sup>² Disjoint means that nothing can be an instance of both specializations, which many implementation languages disallow, but the real world and UML *do* allow. Incomplete means that there could be other kinds of insurance policies that we haven't called out and it is possible to directly instantiate the general `Insurance Policy`.</sup>

<sup>³ If you change a property name, what that means is that, in the context of its owner, that name eclipses the name in the generalized owner. If you "upcast" the specialization, the same property will be have its original name because it is in the context of the generalized owner.</sup>

Comment: Ok thank you Jim L. for this very detailed answer. 
In term of implementation, I guess that is not as straightforward as a simple inheritance, or something like a composition or an aggregation.
Is there a well-known pattern to get such a structure, at a DB level (through an ORM abstraction), and at a programmatic level (no DB consideration)?

Comment: For ORM, see [Class Table Inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) or [Concrete Table Inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html). Each table would have its own specific foreign key. This UML diagram is extremely straightforward to implement using methods in an OO language, so I'm not sure what else to say about that.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you would do that by using [Generalization Sets](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html). This will ensure that the Generalizations from `Italy` and `Italian Guy` (you have a male-only country?) are related and thus you will have the "right" population only.

Comment: I don't fully understand what is described in the link you provided about Generalization Set and the [subsequent example](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/health-insurance-policy-domain-diagram-example.html) . How the link between e.g. in my example _Italy_ and _Italian guy_ is materialized? Is it what they call **power type**?

Comment: You can type each generalization with the specific country (`:France` and `:Italy`). You will probably not need any of the constraints. Alternatively you move the composition down to the specific classes away from the abstractions.